# How to call an implementation of an interface in c++ from another class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an abstract class, let's say A, which contains a pure virtual function with an access specifier as protected. Another class, let's say B, overrides the interface and implement function List().

```
class A {
 public:
  ...
 protected:
  virtual std::vector<std::string> List() = 0;
}
```

```
class B: public A {
 protected:
  std::vector<std::string> List() override {
   //Implementation for the method
  }
}
```

My question is that now I have another class, C, which needs to call implemented interface List() from class B so that I can store the returned result in class C. How can I call an interface in class C?

PS: I can change the access specifier of the method to public in class B if that can solve the problem.

Comment: Making `List` a `protected` member is explicitly saying you *don't* want unrelated types calling `List`. This is contrary to your stated goal.

Comment: You can always expose the protected interface via public method.

Comment: @AdityaKushwah Make `List` public if you intend to for it to be publicly accessible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I can make a new class with the same method (a duplicated) but that would not be a write way to write code. So I was thinking if there is a way I can.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to make a duplicate of `A` or how that would even work.

Comment: I can make the List method from class B public but not from class A. That is how it was coded.

Comment: Is B supposed to comply with the A interface, or not?  It sounds like B is _not_ an A, so why have B inherit from A?

Comment: Why do you want to call List() from C? Maybe C should implement A.

Comment: @R0m1 Class B implements List() and the output from B's List implementation will be used in C's method. Implementing List in both B and C would be redundant. And B's List() has to be implemented in class B because it is being used by other function too. Hence the problem

Comment: @Eljay I dont understand. The pure virtual function is defined in A and implementation is in B so it does comply with A. (If I am understanding your ques correctly).

Comment: @aditya it's not redundant for an interface to have several implementations :)

Comment: Because "I have another class, C, which needs to call implemented interface List() from class B so that I can store the returned result in class C. How can I call an interface in class C?" tells me that C needs a B, not an A, and A doesn't provide what C needs.  Which smells like B is not an A.